# Trying to match today's date with list of custom dates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime, match

**Trying to match today's date with list of custom dates in python**

The code is :

```
holid = ['2021-01-26', '2021-03-11', '2021-03-29', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-14', '2021-04-21',
 '2021-05-13', '2021-07-21', '2021-08-19', '2021-09-10', '2021-10-15', '2021-11-05','2021-11-19']

date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
date

'2021-06-06'

for i in holid:
    i == date
    print("Matched")
```

It's returning wrong output :

```
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
Matched
```

Comment: You are looping over `holid`, but then on each iteration you print "Matched". You are missing an `if` on your `i == date`. Try it with `if i == date:` (and indent the line below it accordingly)

Comment: Also note that today's date does not appear in the list.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to write if statement. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually want to persist the matched/not matched results, you could use a list comprehension here:

```py
holid = ['2021-01-26', '2021-03-11', '2021-03-29', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-14', '2021-04-21', '2021-05-13', '2021-07-21', '2021-08-19', '2021-09-10', '2021-10-15', '2021-11-05','2021-11-19']
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
output = ["Matched" if x == date else "Not Matched" for x in holid]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of there is not an if statement at the end so it is always printing matched, fix this with an if statement:

```
from datetime import datetime

holid = ['2021-01-26', '2021-06-06', '2021-03-11', '2021-03-29', '2021-04-02', '2021-04-14', '2021-04-21',
'2021-05-13', '2021-07-21', '2021-08-19', '2021-09-10', '2021-10-15', '2021-11-05','2021-11-19']

date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
date

'2021-06-06'

for i in holid:
    if i == date:
        print("Matched")
    else:
        print("Not Matched")
```